Strange behaviour listening for scroll event in React
I'm missing something about React I guess. This is the relevant part of the code:
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(1);

  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); 

  const changeCount = () => {
    let tmp = count + 1;
    setCount(tmp);
  };

  const onListScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (count < 5 && containerRef.current && containerRef.current.scrollTop === 0) {
      console.log('count: ' + count);
      changeCount();
    }
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      containerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', onListScroll);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', onListScroll);
      };
    }
  }, [onListScroll]);

Basically I have a div for which I have set a ref.
Everytime I scroll the div to the top I want to increment count variable and print it.
I would expect the above piece of code to print count: 1 the first time I scroll, count: 2 the second time, count: 3 the third time and so on.
But this is what happens:
1st scroll:
count: 1

2nd scroll:
count: 1
count: 2

3rd scroll:
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3

4th scroll:
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4

What am I doing wrong?

You are adding the scroll event listener multiple times: every time the count changes, the reference to onListScroll updates, which means the useEffect will trigger again, which is adding another scroll event listener. I think you should use a empty useEffect (i.e. no dependencies) to register and remove the event listener on mount/unmount.

If you add an console.log('Adding listener'); above the addEventListener line, you\ll see that you keep adding eventlisteners on each call, you should not use onlistScroll as a useEffect dependency.
Since you stated "Basically I have a div", why not use the onScroll prop on a div?


const { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

    const containerRef = useRef(null); 

    const changeCount = () => setCount(p => p + 1);

    const onListScroll = useCallback(() => {
        if (count < 5 && containerRef.current && containerRef.current.scrollTop === 0) {
            console.log('count: ' + count);
            changeCount();
        }
    }, [count]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example: ' + count}</h1>
            <div id='test' ref={containerRef} onScroll={onListScroll}>
                {[...Array(100)].map((e, i) => <span>FOO - BAR<br/></span>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
#test { 
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: scroll;
  
  max-height: 150px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>



